# How to avoid generate negative unique id using Johann's

Tags: java, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am using johann guid to generate alphanumeric ids. And I generate numeric ids using the getTime method in the UUID class(Johann’s UUID).

But sometimes it generates negative isd for numeric Id(ex. -23232323232323). How can I avoid  generating a negative unique id.? Please help me

Comment: If the UUIDs are alphanumeric, why do you care if they are negative or not? If there are letters randomly thrown in, I'd think you wouldn't be using them as a number...

Answer (score 0):

The Math object has an absolute value function, which will take care of the negative value you are concerned with.  However, you risk losing uniqueness.  When does it matter if your numbers are negative?  Below is an example test:

```
public class Test{ 

public static void main(String args[]){
  Integer a = -8;
  double d = -100;
  float f = -90;    

  System.out.println(Math.abs(a));
  System.out.println(Math.abs(d));     
  System.out.println(Math.abs(f));    
  }
}
```

This produces the following result:

```
8
100.0
90.0
```

Comment: Be careful with this as `Math.abs()` may output negative values under certain conditions. One example is when inputting negative 2^31 (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`) as an `int`. (Positive 2^31 is outside of the `int` range, so the output is left as a negative value.)

Comment: But is abs(guid) guaranteed to return a unique number?

Comment: Thanks Smallhacker, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Jay Elston, Math.abs isn't about a unique identifier, it's about getting the absolute value of a number passed in.